# Best method to connect mysql with nodejs expressjs application

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm planning to build a rest api. I'm using NodeJS & ExpressJS to serve the api and mysql as database. What are the best methods to connect mysql with expressjs and what are the pros & cons of it.